# Concurrent connection issue with Redis and Tornado

Tags: python, redis, tornado

I have been load testing [Klassify](https://github.com/fatiherikli/klassify) and I have noticed that Klassify has a problem with concurrent connections to Redis. All is well when Klassify has only one request to handle at a time. When the request count goes up, the connection with Redis gets broken and it will remain broken after that.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it's related to your code, then please update your question with the relevant code. If it's related to that library, you should create an issue on their Github page. But it appears the last activity on their issues page was two years ago. So I doubt if raising issue there would be of any help.

Comment: Thanks xyres, the issue is related to that specific project. As you mentioned, there has been no activity on the issues page so not sure if posting this there will generate any responses.